# Selenium Exception: Object does not match target

Tags: c#, selenium

I am working on writing my first few tests using Selenium. I am running into a problem that I cannot find a solution for. I am attempting to zoom into a chart by using the DragAndDropToOffset call, however, I keep getting the same exception. From what I've worked out it seems to happen when the Perform() call is made.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.Id, Using = "chart")]
private IWebElement _chart;  

new Actions(WebDriverContext.Current).DragAndDropToOffset(_chart, 50, 0).Build().Perform();
```

Result: rangeSystem.Reflection.TargetException : Object does not match target type.

I originally thought the web driver was the problem, but it is being using in multiple other places to handle element finding and page navigation.

Am I overlooking something in that small piece of code or should I be looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Try other option:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.clickAndHold(From).build().perform();
action.moveToElement(To).build().perform();
action.release(To).build().perform();
```

From & to must be IWebElements :

```
IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By...);
```